# Synchronous WebClient Download In Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services, json, webclient

I need do download a string (specifically the JSON array result from a PHP webservice), as a function that returns a string, not DownloadStringAsync. I need this because I am writing a function that downloads the string, and then converts it to a JsonArray.

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, I am developing a Silverlight application, and any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to force Silverlight to be synchronous when a synchronous API was so deliberately omitted. Why not ask the better question: "how can I do this asynchronously?" rather that trying to bash square pegs into round holes.

Comment: @spender Because lots of people out there (like me) think that programming with tangled webs of callbacks and event handlers can get real messy, real quick. However trying to squash a square peg into a round hole can be just as messy, if not more so.

Comment: @spender And thinking about it, if you have any design hints that make asynchronous programming easier/more organized, I (and the OP, probably) would be all ears.

Comment: @Phil See my answer, Phil. Since I discovered coroutines I no longer feel like stabbing myself in the crotch when handling async workflows in Silverlight.

Comment: Silverlight tries to enforce the async model because any other type of activity on the main thread would block the UI activity.  This was a trade-off for having the users become intimate with utilizing threading to create apps. You should simply call this service async and in a callback handle the result by testing if it was successful and then converting it to a JsonArray.  Personally I am more prone to use lambda callbacks rather than hooking up an event handler, but there are trade-offs to each to consider.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is not synchronous workflows (this would be very difficult, if not impossible, in Silverlight). Rather you want to be able to manage *asynchronous* workflows *sequentially*. You want to be able to say "Download this string from the web service, and then convert the string to a JSON array", without the messiness of handling callbacks and events.

Well there is good news and bad news. The good news is that there is a solution to this problem - it's called [Coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine). Coroutines are a way of halting execution of a sequential piece of code until the last part has completed, even if that part is asynchronous.

The bad news is that coroutines are not natively implemented in C# (although they are [coming in C# 5](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/10/coroutines_with_c_5s_await.html)). You can implement your own sequential workflows, and there is an absolutely brilliant article about it [here](http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/03/sequential-asynchronous-workflows-in.html). It's a long article and it's a little difficult if you've never done it before.

But despair not! There is a simpler way. [Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) is an MVVM framework that actually has a simple coroutine implementation. In fact, you could quite easily use the Caliburn.Micro coroutines without using any other part of the framework, if you really want to. The creator of Caliburn.Micro, Rob Eisenberg, has an excellent article about coroutines, including theory and practice, [here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/rob_eisenberg/archive/2010/08/21/caliburn-micro-soup-to-nuts-part-5-iresult-and-coroutines.aspx).

Basically your code will end up looking something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> DoTheThing() {
  var json = new FetchString("webserviceaddress.asmx");
  yield return json;
  var jsonStr = json.Result;
  var jsonArray = createJsonArray(jsonStr);
  // do stuff with the array
}
```

At least I think that's what you're looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're using MVVM Light, Matt Hamilton created coroutines for that framework: http://matthamilton.net/coroutines-with-mvvm-light